# Is it possible to run an animation while angular is updating a component?

Tags: angular

Take the following (simiplified) code as an example:

```
/* TimeLine component */
<ul class="timeline">
    <li *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <timeLineItem [message]="message"></timeLineItem>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the timeLineItem:

```
/* TimeLineItem component */
<div> {{message.author}} </div>
```

again, this code is very simplified to give a good example.
Now as soon as I set the value of `messages` on the timeLine component the entire page freezes and only becomes responsive again as soon as the timeLine component has created all its timeLineItem's and the browser has rendered them. With the amount of entries in the `messages` array this takes a few seconds. During that time I would like to have some kind of loading animation running. But, as I said, when I set the `messages` array the browser and thus any animation freezes.
Is there any way I can have an animation running during the update and render process?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be handled in several ways. The best one in my opinion is using virtual scrolling (only a few of your components will be rendered at the same time and no animations will be required). Possible solution can be found here https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

The other way is to use css animations istead of js ones. They are calculated in a separate thread and won't be stopped by have js calculations

Comment: I tried your suggestion with a css animation, but unfortunately it didnt work.
For testing purposes I added a div with an infinite css animation defined like this:
    #containerAnim{
        background-color: aqua;
        animation: colorChange 2s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes colorChange{
        0%, 100%{
            background-color: aqua;
        }
        50%{
            background-color: crimson;
        }
    }
but again, as soon as the timeLine component is updated with all the messages this animation freezes as well.
Anyway i'll add virtual scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like ng-block-ui. I wrap the entire HTML in the block element. I do this in app.component.html.

```
<block-ui>
...
</block-ui>
```

Then, in a global service I expose a property IsLoading

```
  private _loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  set isLoading(value: boolean) {
    this._loading.next(value);
  }
  get loading() {
    return this._loading.asObservable();
  }
```

Next, in app.component.ts, I subscribe and show the loading spinner.

```
this.appSvc.loading.subscribe( isLoading => {
   if (isLoading) {
      this.blockUI.start('Loading...');
   } else {
      this.blockUI.stop();
   }
});
```

Here is an example using it with an HTTP post:

```
  this.appSvc.isLoading = true;
  this.http.post<UploadInfo>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/BalanceUpload`, formData, { headers: {'filename': droppedFile.fileEntry.name, 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}, reportProgress: true})
     .subscribe(
        data => {            
           this.appSvc.isLoading = false;
           this.uploadInfo = data[0];
        },
        error => {
           this.appSvc.isLoading = false;                                     
        }
      )
   });
```

You can read more at: [ng-block-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-block-ui)

Now, from anywhere in your app you can set isLoading(true|false) to show the spinner.